# Are canvas hit regions still available in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas, browser-support

We were using the experimental **Hit Region** feature in our web application for accessibility reasons. We've just found out that this feature is no longer working in Google Chrome. I can't find anything about it on official sites.

Here is a simple demo of the "Hit Region" feature:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// head
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 75, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();

// eyes
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(70, 80, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.arc(130, 80, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fill();

try
{
  ctx.addHitRegion({id: "eyes"}); // NO SUPPORT => Exception

  // mouth :-)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 110, 50, 0, Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();
}
catch
{
  // mouth :-(
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 160, 40, Math.PI, 0, false);
  ctx.stroke();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  if (event.region) {
    alert('hit region: ' + event.region);
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Running the code snippet above:

- If the feature is [supported and enabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion#Browser_compatibility) in the browser, it should draw a smiling face and moving the mouse over the eyes should open an alert box.
- If the feature is not active, the face should be sad.

The demo is working in Firefox 61.0.1, but is not working in Google Chrome 67.0.3396.99 and I can no longer find the according flag under `chrome://flags/` to enable it. Does anybody know if this features was removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The "Experimental Canvas Features" flag has been removed from Chrome in the latest Canary ([CL](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/957646)). To play around with experimental canvas features, you could turn on the "Experimental Web Platform features" flag.*
>   <sub>([source](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/blink-dev/14WpfTddUDI/HNlrrpZxBQAJ))</sub>

This is the new flag you're looking for:

[image]

If you enable that flag, your snippet will render a happy smiley.

Comment: Thanks! Can we find out the official version number of Chrome (not Canary) in which they changed this?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly: Looks like I forgot to copy the link in the comment.